# Sound produced by muscle tightening

Tags: human-biology

If you are at some quiet place, you will hear some mild noise when you tighten your jaw. Why is this? Is this sound produced by face/jaw muscle?

Comment: You can do something similar with your ears as well [What causes “ear rumbling”?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/80419/27918) and [What is official term for contraction induced muscle “vibration”?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/80139/27918)