# What is official term for contraction induced muscle "vibration"?

Tags: muscles

I can activate my tensor tympani muscles at will, it makes me hear rumbling bass sound becose the muscles "shiver / "vibrate" when contracted. Also when I put cleched fist to my ear I can hear it too. I read all muscles make makes this rumbling low frequency sound when contracted.

I wanted to study this thing but I run into the problem becose I dont know how is this muscle vibration officialy called. I dont know what words should I type to get relevant search results. I dont want anything about shivers, tremors or other stuff, I just want to know how is the normal muscle "rumble" called.

Comment: you may be able to post an answer to [What causes “ear rumbling”?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/80419/27918)